# Laravel 4.2 crashing XAMPP

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-4, xampp

I have been developing using Laravel 4.1 for the last 2 weeks on my Windows 7 computer with XAMPP on it with no problems.

In composer.json I changed 4.1 to

```
 "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
```

After running a composer update the services.json file is removed and not re-created. I can re-create it doing php artisan serve however the website now runs incredibly slowly and after loading about 3 different pages XAMPP crashes and Apache must be manually restarted.

If changing back to

```
 "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
```

and running a composer update the services.json file is automatically created and the site runs perfectly again.

This appears in the apache error log when it crashes

```
 [Fri Aug 22 15:30:13.436800 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2732:tid 252] AH00354:      Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
 [Fri Aug 22 15:31:13.734800 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4188:tid 240] AH00428:      Parent: child process 2732 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
```

Any suggestions?

*edit*
Also getting these errors in the laravel.log

```
 [2014-08-22 14:58:36] mysite.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08S02]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SMux Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].

 Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08S02]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SMux Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].  (SQL: exec PHABCART_GetSubCats 32596, justgloves.co.uk)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:600
```

Comment: Ditch XAMPP and [install a standard Apache+PHP sever manually](http://superuser.com/questions/748117/how-to-manually-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-windows) (you can skip the MySQL part since you seem to already have a MS SQL server installed).

Comment: What version of PHP does your XAMPP have?

Comment: 5.4 as I couldn't find the dlls for connecting to mssql with 5.5

Comment: André I have installed what you suggested and apache crashes with 4.2 and not 4.1